# PHP: HTML: send HTML select option attribute in POST

Tags: php, html, html-parsing

I want to send the selected item value along with some attribute (stud_name) value. Is there any functionality in PHP to do so?

Here is the example one.

```
<form name="add">
    Age: 

    <select name="age">
         <option value="1" stud_name="sre">23</option>
         <option value="2" stud_name="sam">24</option>
         <option value="5" stud_name="john">25</option>
     </select>

    <input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
```

Comment: AFAIK, you'll have to do it using javascript/jquery. I don't think it is possible in PHP alone

Comment: I think the values are the IDs of the students. After getting IDs also you can student names (from database), right? Don't rely on the user side.

Comment: @asprin, If then , how to do in js

Comment: or you can add the stud_name to the value with an delimiter. And after post you can divide them on the delimiter.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
<form name="add" method="post">
     <p>Age:</p>
     <select name="age">
        <option value="1_sre">23</option>
        <option value="2_sam">24</option>
        <option value="5_john">25</option>
     </select>
     <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

You will have the selected value in `$_POST['age']`, e.g. `1_sre`. Then you will be able to split the value and get the `'stud_name'`.

```
$stud = explode("_",$_POST['age']);
$stud_id = $stud[0];
$stud_name = $stud[1];
```

Answer (score 8):

You can do this with JQuery

Simply:

```
   <form name='add'>
   Age: <select id="age" name='age'>
   <option value='1' stud_name='sre'>23</option>
   <option value='2' stud_name='sam'>24</option>
   <option value='5' stud_name='john'>25</option>
   </select>
   <input type='hidden' id="name" name="name" value=""/>
   <input type='submit' name='submit'/>
   </form>
```

Add this code in Header section:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
```

Now JQuery function

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(function() {
      $("#age").change(function(){
      var studentNmae= $('option:selected', this).attr('stud_name');
      $('#name').val(studentNmae);
   });
});
</script>
```

you can use both values as

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$value = $_POST['age'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use JavaScript. The browser will only send the `value` of the selected option (so its not PHP's fault).

What your JS should do is hook into the form's submit event and create a hidden field with the value of the selected option's `stud_name` value. This hidden field will then get sent to the server.

That being said ... you shouldn't relay on the client to provide the correct data. You already know what `stud_name` should be for a given value on the server (since you are outputting it). So just apply the same logic when you are processing the form.

Answer (score 0):

just combine the value and the stud_name e.g. 1_sre and split the value when get it into php. Javascript seems like hammer to crack a nut. N.B. this method assumes you can edit the the html. Here is what the html might look like:

```
<form name='add'>
Age: <select name='age'>
     <option value='1_sre'>23</option>
     <option value='2_sam>24</option>
     <option value='5_john>25</option>
     </select>
<input type='submit' name='submit'/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery function.

```
<form name='add'>
   <input type='text' name='stud_name' id="stud_name" value=""/>
   Age: <select name='age' id="age">
   <option value='1' stud_name='sre'>23</option>
   <option value='2' stud_name='sam'>24</option>
   <option value='5' stud_name='john'>25</option>
   </select>
   <input type='submit' name='submit'/>
</form>
```

jquery code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {
          $("#age").change(function(){
          var option = $('option:selected', this).attr('stud_name');
          $('#stud_name').val(option);
       });
    });
</script>
```