# Making checkboxes take data along if checked to another page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to make a page which shows data from the database and I'd like to have checkboxes next to the data to select the data with the checkbox and take it to another page, currently how I display the data from the database and the checkbox is

```
foreach ( wc_get_order( $ordernumber )->get_items() as $item ){
                echo "<input type='checkbox' name='productinfo[]' value='Yes'>";                echo '<p>';
                echo __('Tuotteen nimi: ' ) . $item->get_name() . '<br>';
                echo __('Määrä: ' ) . $item->get_quantity() . '<br>';
                echo __('Tuotteen hinta: ' )  . wc_price($item->get_total()) . '</p>';
            }
```

is it possible to make the checkbox take all that info with it on submit button press and take it to another page and display it there? 
Feel free to ask if there's something unclear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your code inside form define that page in the action

```
<form action="demo.php" method="post">
 <?php

    foreach ( wc_get_order( $ordernumber )->get_items() as $item ){
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='productinfo[]' value='".$item->get_name(). $item->get_quantity() .$item->get_quantity()"'>";
        }


?>

 <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

**Another file**- where you want to send your data

```
<?php 
$test = $_POST['productinfo'];

for($i=0; $i<sizeof($test); $i++) {
list($name, $quantity, $total) = explode(" ", $test[$i]);
echo "Name-".$name;
echo "Quantity".$quantity;
echo "Total".$total;
}


?>
```

You can perform any action to take out the data. In this case i am spliting up the data using space

This might not be the perfect solution 
but it works

Hope it helps

Comment: Did not get it to quite work yet, doesn't display anything with the foreach

Comment: it will put all the data you need inside your checkbox value and at the second page you can take out the value using $_POST  and here we are not printing anything actually we are putting all the data inside checkbox values. what you will see is checkboxes equal to your item count

Comment: Ah I see, I will test it out.

Comment: :) Glad to hear that . can i have vote and tick please

Comment: on a closer look It seems to print out different parts of the name instead of the correct quantity, total and name values

Comment: That is the only solution you have ,or you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578559/php-html-send-html-select-option-attribute-in-post    and see it also have the same pattern